# Squash all commits with commit messages that match a certain pattern

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to squash all Git commits with commit messages that match a certain pattern?

Ideally this would be non-interactive - it would be automatic at the command line.

Answer (score 3):

`git rebase -i` creates a todo file and calls editor; it's supposed that the user edits the file and git interprets it. The file is in [well-known format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode). Instead of interactive editor I create a shell script that edits the file non-interactively; I use `sed -i` to edit it in place; I use `s///` search command to find `pick` commands with your `$PATTERN` and replace them with `squash` commands.

File `squash.sh`; put your pattern (basic regular expression style) there:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec sed -i 's/^pick \([^ ]\+\) $PATTERN.\+$/squash \1/' $1
```

Command line:

```
chmod +x squash.sh
GIT_EDITOR=./squash.sh git rebase --interactive $COMMIT_ID
```

Comment: ok in English can you explain a little more about what is going here? thx

Comment: nice that is cool, can you make a screenshare video to demonstrate how it works? lol just kidding :) thanks

Comment: And can you get Git to make this work in non-interactive mode? :)

Comment: Replacing `GIT_EDITOR` with a non-interactive script does exactly that — makes git rebase non-interactive.

Comment: @Alexander Mills, the `chmod` command gives the `squash.sh` script executable permissions, so that it can be executed.
`GIT_EDITOR=./squash.sh git rebase --interactive $COMMIT_ID`
The `GIT_EDITOR=./squash.sh` part tells git to use the file that phd created as our editor (instead of your normal editor, which could be vim, emacs, Atom, etc). This file just finds commits that match the regex.
After that the command is the normal git rebase command, nothing to see here. In case it isn't obvious, you will need to understand basic regex to tell `squash.sh` what to look for in commit messages.

Answer (score 1):

This fails to satisfy your *Ideally this would be non-interactive…* request, but I do this to achieve effectively the same thing: https://twitter.com/csswizardry/status/843040649666596865

The more general solution is as follows

```
:g/<pattern>/normal cws
```

Whch means:

- `:g/` – Find lines containing…
- `<pattern>/` – …this string
- `normal` – Enter normal mode
- `cws` – change word to s (for Squash)

Comment: sorry I am too dumb to interpret this answer, could you clarify it a bit? e.g., I do not see "git" command anywhere here lol

Comment: I think he's saying you need to do an interactive rebase

Comment: an interactive rebase uses vi commands. csswizardry's answer is a way to do find/replace in vi

Comment: @AlexanderMills: It’s not a case of dumbness :) Did you take a look at the link? It’s an interactive rebase using Vim to mark _all Git commits with commit messages that match a certain pattern_ for squashing.